# validation not working after selected option?

Tags: javascript, validation

Am trying to validate a form, now i have added a dropdown: "yes or no"
if chooses "yes" it will show another "one more div"
but if user chooses "no" - validation works fine and form submitted.
This is the problem for me please provide the solution for this.

```html
<select id="offerdeliver" name="offerdeliver" onkeypress="return enter_check(event)">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="Inbound">Inbound</option>
       <option value="Transferred">Transferred</option>
    </select>
<select id="topuploan" name="topuploan" onkeypress="return enter_check(event)">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
       <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
<input type="text" maxlength="15" name="existingloannumber" id="existingloannumber" onfocus="return ReUniqueReference_val();" onkeypress="return AlphaNumSplcharCheck(event);" />
```

Comment: what is the issue here? not able to get it!

Comment: share your problem and code .... ?

Comment: sorry i have posted the question in wrong format.,

Comment: now i got solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add another div only if it's yes, simply use an onchange, and then in Javascript, check for Yes.

```
 "onchange="addDiv()"
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function addDiv(){
var x = document.getElementById("topuploan").value;
if(x == "Yes"){
//Add Div or do what you need
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: i can able to change, it has another validation field? how include validation for that?

Comment: @shanths Sorry, but could you phrase this question differently? There is an error with your English Syntax.

Comment: am closing this task, with your answer.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.